# How to download an Html table into excel file using asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have an Html table as such:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="Messages" id="idTbl" runat="server">
    <tr>
        <th>date</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="myHot_smsMessages_new">
        <td>01/01/2014</td>
        <td>Some Subject No 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="myHot_smsMessages_new">
        <td>10/12/2013</td>
        <td>Some subject no 2</td>
    </tr>                    
</table>
```

and on the server side:

```
protected void ExportToXLS(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/x-msexcel";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=ExcelFile.xls"); Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(); HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw); idTbl.RenderControl(hw);
    Response.Write(tw.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In what way does it "not work"?  Is the HTML content successfully downloaded but Excel doesn't read it?  Is the content not downloaded at all?  Where does it fail?

Comment: also have you considered the alternative, the HTML came from a data source, it would be easier to convert that data source to Excel rather than the HTML.

Comment: when debugging, I go through all line codes and eventually the page returns an empty page (maybe it happens due to some inner process in my website, not sure). cjb110 - I shall look into it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured out two solutions, the first one is redirecting from my page to a generic handler (send the ByteStream) and in the handler do something like user3851829 suggested below

What I did was something similar, only I took the content from a repeater and then rendered it into the stringBuilder as such:

```
protected void ExportToXLS(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Notifications.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        HtmlTextWriter tw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        repeaterID.DataSource = Session["SomeDataFromSession"] as List<SomeObject>;
        repeaterID.DataBind();

        rptNotifications.RenderControl(tw);

        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

**Both answers are working !**

Comment: What if there is some UL or inner table, will the excel sheet display the html output or just the html code?

Answer (score 2):

```
static StringBuilder StrBuilder = new StringBuilder();


        protected void lnkExcel_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //ExportGrid.ExportExcel(griditem);
            ConfigureEmployeeExport();

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/msexcel";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=ExcelFile.xls");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(StrBuilder);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        }




public void ConfigureEmployeeExport()
{
    StrBuilder.Append("<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' class='Messages' id='idTbl' runat='server'><tr><th>date</th><th>Subject</th></tr><tr class='myHot_smsMessages_new'><td>01/01/2014</td><td>Some Subject No 1</td></tr><tr class='myHot_smsMessages_new'><td>10/12/2013</td><td>Some subject no 2</td></tr></table>");

}
```